# Masonry v1.1.0 crash when using safeAreaLayoutGuide

Tags: ios, safearealayoutguide, masonry-ios-osx

this crash:

```
make.top.left.right.equalTo(self.view.mas_safeAreaLayoutGuide);
```

but this ok:

```
make.top.equalTo(self.view.mas_safeAreaLayoutGuideTop);
make.left.equalTo(self.view.mas_safeAreaLayoutGuideLeft);
make.right.equalTo(self.view.mas_safeAreaLayoutGuideRight);
```

why? I use masonry

It's the main code:

```
- (void)configView {
    self.view.backgroundColor = kColor666;
    UIView *headView = [UIView new];
    headView.backgroundColor = kColorWhite;
    [self.view addSubview:headView];
    [headView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
        make.top.equalTo(self.view.mas_safeAreaLayoutGuideTop); //ok
        make.left.equalTo(self.view.mas_safeAreaLayoutGuideLeft);   //ok
        make.right.equalTo(self.view.mas_safeAreaLayoutGuideRight); //ok
        make.top.left.right.equalTo(self.view.mas_safeAreaLayoutGuide);   //crash
    } else {
        make.top.equalTo(self.mas_topLayoutGuide);
        make.left.right.equalTo(self.view);
    }
    make.height.mas_equalTo(120);
    }];
}
```

it seems nothing wrong.
I just want to write less code.

Comment: Can you provide the rest of the code?

Comment: ok, i add the main code.

Comment: Your GitHub issue is still open. :( https://github.com/SnapKit/Masonry/issues/477